# Link Between Integer Partition and Partition of a Set

Tags: integer-partitions, set-partition

**Definition.**
Let $A$ be a non-empty set. A collection $P$ of subsets $A_1,A_2,A_3,\ldots$ of $A$ is called a **partition** of $A$ if the following three conditions hold:

1. $\emptyset \notin P$,
2. $A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3 \cup \cdots = A$, and
3. For all $i$ and $j$, if $i \ne j$, then $A_i \cap A_j = \emptyset$.

**Definition.** Let $n$ be a positive integer. A partition of $n$ is a finite sequence $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3,\ldots\lambda_k$ of positive integers such that $\lambda_1 \ge \lambda_2 \ge \lambda_3 \ge \cdots \ge \lambda_k$ and
$$\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3+\cdots+\lambda_k = n.$$

I want to know the relationship/link between the partition of set with a partition of a positive integer, since the word 'partition' used is the same. But, I still didn't get it.
What I tried was as follows: Let $n$ be a positive integer. Define a set $A$ of finite positive integers $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3,\ldots,\lambda_k$ for which their sum is equal to $n$ and form a non-increasing sequence, that is, $\lambda_1 \ge \lambda_2 \ge \lambda_3 \ge \ldots \ge \lambda_k$.

Next, form clopen subintervals $[\lambda_k, \lambda_{k-1}), \ldots, [\lambda_2, \lambda_1), [\lambda_1,\lambda_1]$. Then, the set which contain these subintervals is a partition of $A$, and so, such $\lambda$ is called a partition of $n$.

Is this correct? Any help please? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: The union of your clopen intervals is a partition of the interval $[\lambda_1,\lambda_k]$ (obviously). This does not contradict to use the word partition in the second context (sum of $\lambda_i$ equals $n$). If we always have to use single words that uniquely describe a mathematical definition we would run out of possibilities fast.

Comment: Typo: the interval is $[\lambda_k,\lambda_1]\,.$

Comment: And one more thing. Why did you call those intervals *clopen*? I know the defintion. Just don't get why topology has anything to do with this. If so: what topology you have in mind?

Comment: And if you want intervals that partition $[0,n]$ just take $[0,\lambda_k),[\lambda_k,\lambda_k+\lambda_{k-1}),\dots,[\lambda_k+\dots+\lambda_2,n]\,.$

Comment: @KurtG. So, my attempt was correct?

Comment: It was what it was: a partition of $[\lambda_1,\lambda_k]$ (obviously). If that was what you wanted it was correct.

Comment: @KurtG. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a set $A$ with $n$ elements and a partition of $A$ in subsets $A_1, \dots, A_k$. If you call $\lambda_i$ the cardinality of $A_i$, after ordering the cardinalities of the subsets, then you get a partition of $n$, because the $A_i$ are disjoint, so $\lambda_1 + \dots + \lambda_k = n$.

Comment: This does not really answer OP's question why the word partition is used in two contexts.

Comment: The OP wrote "I want to know the relationship/link between the partition of set with a partition of a positive integer". I think my answer explains the link

Comment: It does. But OP's question is one of the typical ones where someone gets confused by words. You did not address that.